# Seeking example Python code using @jit with GPU to loop over every pixel in large images

Tags: python, image, for-loop, numba, gpu

I'm running Python 3.6.8 on Windows 10.  I have a Python function that performs a sequence of steps at every pixel in a large batch of images.  The code is currently implemented with for loops, and I want to explore using @jit and GPU to speed up the loops.  For this, I tried the code shown below from following tutorial: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/running-python-script-on-gpu/

```
from numba import jit, cuda
import numpy as np
# to measure exec time
from timeit import default_timer as timer

# normal function to run on cpu
def func(a):
    for i in range(10000000):
        a[i] += 1

# function optimized to run on gpu
@jit(target="cuda")
def func2(a):
    for i in range(10000000):
        a[i] += 1

if __name__ == "__main__":
    n = 10000000
    a = np.ones(n, dtype=np.float64)
    b = np.ones(n, dtype=np.float32)
    #
    start = timer()
    func(a)
    print("without GPU:", timer() - start)

    start = timer()
    func2(a)
    print("with GPU:", timer() - start)
```

The code yields the following error on my machine:

```
  File "D:\Anaconda\envs\py_3_6_8\lib\site-packages\numba\core\decorators.py", line 209, in wrapper
    **dispatcher_args)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'py_func'
```

Since the error seems to be caused by site package code, I'm at a dead-end.

If the code above works for you, could you please let me know your Python version?  I'm running Python 3.6.8 under Windows 10, which should all be compatible with numba, but I'm not positive.  Also, does anyone have a working example similar to the code above they could share?

Answer (score 0):

Found this here [CUDA GPU processing: TypeError: compile_kernel() got an unexpected keyword argument 'boundscheck'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61982672/cuda-gpu-processing-typeerror-compile-kernel-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argum)

```
from numba import vectorize, jit, cuda 
import numpy as np 
from timeit import default_timer as timer 


def func(a):                                 
    for i in range(10000000): 
        a[i]+= 1    

@vectorize(['float64(float64)'], target ="cuda")                         
def func2(x): 
    return x+1

if __name__=="__main__": 
    n = 10000000                            
    a = np.ones(n, dtype = np.float64) 

    start = timer() 
    func(a) 
    print("without GPU:", timer()-start)     

    start = timer() 
    func2(a) 
    print("with GPU:", timer()-start)
```